# QTabBar Tab's Text Disappears When Moving

Tags: c++, qt

When a user clicks and drags a tab in a QTabBar, the text of the tab, and in fact the entire tab itself, disappears until it is "dropped". How Do you stop this from happening?

Comment: Maybe you can add some screen shots and update the description a bit

Comment: Turns out it's a known Qt bug.